# Why is "The choir of bell-flowers" referred to as "a fragment of a long poem" in the subtitle?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

*The Choir of Bell-Flowers* by Pavlo Tychyna in *The Complete Early Poetry Collection* has the subtitle "A fragment of a long poem". What does this mean? Was that added by the translator or by the author? Is this the complete poem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subtitle is present in the [Ukrainian original](https://ukrclassic.com.ua/katalog/t/tichina-pavlo/891-pavlo-tichina-khor-lisovikh-dzvinochkiv-urivok-iz-poemi): "Хор лісових дзвіночків (уривок із поеми)" ["Chorus of forest bells (excerpt from a poem)"]. So it definitely was not added by the translator, and seems indeed to be the original title of the work.